# Can you set the range of the secondary y-axis in the extension dygraphs for QlikSense?

Tags: dygraphs, qliksense

I'm experimenting with dygraphs for QlikSense (http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/56728f52d1e497241ae6987f), to be able to control the line width in graphs. However, I cannot find a way to set min/max range of the secondary y-axis. Is this possible? Under "Graph options" you can control e.g. the labels and grid lines of the secondary axis, but under the tab "Axes and chart area" only a single `y-axis range` is found, which controls the primary axis.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Think that this question should be asked in Branch or open an issue in the extension repository - https://github.com/danielpierre/qlik-sense-dygraphs/issues

Comment: @StefanStoichev Maybe you're right. I'm not familiar with those forums though and thought that there might be some users here as well.

Comment: Just for the record: issue now [opened at the github-page](https://github.com/danielpierre/qlik-sense-dygraphs/issues/8), as suggested. @StefanStoichev